# Easiest way to install a GUI backend for matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, user-interface

I have been struggling to get plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`. Obviously, the problem is

```
temp.py:58: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

I realised that there are multiple backends to switch to, and 's snippet helped me list all inactive GUI backends.

```py
import matplotlib
gui_env = [i for i in matplotlib.rcsetup.interactive_bk]
non_gui_backends = matplotlib.rcsetup.non_interactive_bk
print ("Non Gui backends are:", non_gui_backends)
print ("Gui backends I will test for", gui_env)
for gui in gui_env:
    print ("testing", gui)
    try:
        matplotlib.use(gui,warn=False, force=True)
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        print ("    ",gui, "Is Available")
        plt.plot([1.5,2.0,2.5])
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.suptitle(gui)
        plt.show()
        print ("Using ..... ",matplotlib.get_backend())
    except:
        print ("    ",gui, "Not found")
```

To which I got

```
testing GTK3Agg
     GTK3Agg Not found
testing GTK3Cairo
     GTK3Cairo Not found
testing MacOSX
     MacOSX Not found
testing nbAgg
     nbAgg Not found
testing Qt4Agg
     Qt4Agg Not found
testing Qt4Cairo
     Qt4Cairo Not found
testing Qt5Agg
     Qt5Agg Not found
testing Qt5Cairo
     Qt5Cairo Not found
testing TkAgg
     TkAgg Not found
testing TkCairo
     TkCairo Not found
testing WebAgg
     WebAgg Not found
testing WX
     WX Not found
testing WXAgg
     WXAgg Not found
testing WXCairo
     WXCairo Not found
```

#### Some methods to setup a GUI backend suggest reinstalling python after installing some dependencies but I am looking for a simpler method (if any exists) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went across methods and found the simplest method: Use `TkAgg` backend.

1. Install `tkinter`

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-tk
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

2. Specify this backend in your Python script

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg', force=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Now you can freely call `plt.show()` for your plots and stay happy :)

Comment: I installed tkinter on Windows upon setup, and I tried your solution, but when I run `plt.show()`, nothing is produced. When I run the snippet posted in the question, it says that `TkAgg` is not found. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: @MRichards can you check what all backeds do you have available (after the installation), using the script mentioned in the question?